# Trying to install hercules, unable to access url for install

Tags: software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I am following this guide to install hercules:

https://debian-administration.org/article/484/Running_GNU/Linux_Debian_s390_under_a_i386

This URL gives 403 error (forbidden):

http://people.debian.org/~mdz/hercules/Debian-3.0r1.3390

Comment: The document you are following is out of date and most of links are broken. what is your distribution ?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04 on my computer and the hyperion-master for the to run the s390 i have several different distros

Comment: To install hercules on your Ubuntu, use: `sudo apt install hercules`.

Comment: @Zanna: Just did it ;)

Answer (score 1):

The document you are following is out of date and most of its links are broken.

To install hercules on your Ubuntu, use:

```
sudo apt install hercules
```

For more information: [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)